# How can I make the compass point to a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a hunting Minecraft map, and each hunter has a tracking compass that points to the nearest player. My friend said that I need a plugin or mod (I don't know what a plugin is!). The plugin thing seems to be complicated so I want to know if there's a way to do this with commands only.

I tried setting spawnpoints of the hunters to the hunted but this only works if the hunter dies: next time they respawn, the compass points to it but only where the hunted stood when the hunter died.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: uhm... i have: set new spawnpoint repeatedly. and i see this comment of you like for 1 billion times! I know that it is better not to rely on others, you should try your way out first but the thing is I HAVE TRIED MY BEST IT TOOK ME 3 DAYS THINKING AND TESTING!!!!

Comment: @Frank he did try something, even though he did not post the commands he used. I assume it was something like running `/execute @a[team=hunted] ~ ~ ~ /spawnpoint @a[team=hunter] ~ ~ ~`

Comment: Wow... Exactly. I connect it to a fast redstone clock,so that the hunted's location could be updated. But, as I have mentioned before, the compass only updates when the hunters respawn.

Comment: Adding in what you have tried is important. Otherwise, we might be retreading the same ground you've already gone over.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not being specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked, and `/setworldspawn` does change the compass immediately. Try running on a clock:

```
/execute @p[team=hunted] ~ ~ ~ setworldspawn ~ ~ ~
```

if you encounter any problems, please leave a comment and I will look into it.

Comment: @ash4fun I think you should use @a instead of @p

Comment: @RudolfJelínek There can only be one worldspawn, so it doesn't make sense to set it to more than one person. `@r` should work though.

Comment: @ash4fun I just said that because there were problems with @p[something] in older MC versions :D

Comment: @RudolfJelínek Problems in older versions are irrelevant because `/execute` was introduced in 1.8 and there are no "issues" with `@p`.

Comment: @Skylinerw I'll remember that for further answers

Comment: 1.13 syntax from suggested edit:  `/execute as @p[team=hunted] at @s run setworldspawn ~ ~ ~`

Answer (score 1):

First, a quick note: this command does ***NOT WORK IN JAVA EDITION***.
As of 2020, the best way to do this is with a **repeating command block set to always active** and with this command set in it: `/execute [insert prey gamertag] ~ ~ ~ setworldspawn ~ ~ ~`.
This will work, but you need to do 2 quick things in order for it to work 100% of the time. First, give the command `/gamerule commandblockoutput false` so that chat isn't constantly filled saying the spawnpoint was changed. Second, you need to set a ticking area around the command block. You'll need the coordinates for this. You need to use `/tickingarea add [insert coordinates] [insert coordinates]`. The ticking area must be the 3x3 area around the command block, with the command block in the center. Now just make sure the hunter has a large supply of compasses and set their personal spawnpoint near the command block to prevent them from respawning on top of you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I solved all my problems with "/execute" there was an "@" after I think it was this . Basically I used a tag named Runner and made the world spawn wherever they were with a repeating_command_block it the command was something like this:

```
/execute @(/tag=Runner) setworldspawn ~ ~ ~.
```

I hope this helps any one with a problem setting up an assassin vs speed runner world.